# List all the tasks for a given Process in the order of execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, bpmn, flowable

This is a basic functionality and I see repeated questions , but unfortunately no clear answer yet.

How do I print/list all the tasks in the given process ( finished / unfinished ) in the order of execution.

The two solution I found on the forum are working as expected

```
repositoryService.getBpmnModel().getFlowElements() - Does not print in the order of execution . Printed in the order of definition
historyService.createHistoricActivityQuery - Does not print all Service task
```

How do I just list all the task under the given process.

Comment: Can you please help me to solve my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60925265/6097074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by tasks you mean all the elements in the process then you can use the `HistoricActivityInstanceQuery` to get the information about them.

The code would look something like:

```
List<HistoricActivityInstance> activityInstances = historyService
    .createHistoricActivityInstanceQuery().
    .processInstanceId(processInstanceId)
    .orderByHistoricActivityInstanceStartTime().asc()
    .list();
```

In order to see if a `HistoricActivityInstance` is finished or not you'll need to check the `HistoricActivityInstance#getEndTime()`. When that is `null` it means that the activity is not finished, if it is `null` then it means it is finished.

Comment: This is not returning all the tasks. I can startEvent, sequenceFlow and the first UserTask

Comment: This is returning all the tasks that were / are executing for a given process instance. If you are looking into the order in which they will be executed then I misunderstood the question

Comment: yeh. My Mistake sorry. I could see all the tasks getting printed. And I also , see the order is also correct.  Is this order dependable or it is based on how bpmn is written

Comment: The order that you will get from the `HistoricActivityInstnaceQuery` is the one you requests in the query. In this example it is the order of which the tasks were started

Comment: Sorry to bump. Just a confusion.
The HistoricActivity list, only tasks that are complete and the next task alone.
Support i have task 1 - 4. And if the tasks 1,2 are complete, then I can see only task 1, task 2 and task 3, but not task 4. If i finish task 3, i can see task 4.

So as a whole the historic activity displayed [ executed + next task ].
How to I get the full list of tasks

Comment: The list contains all completed tasks and all started tasks. It doesn't have anything about future tasks. All tasks from a process can be retrieved via the `BpmnModel`, but not in an execution order

Comment: so I guess. There aint no API to get all the tasks in the order of execution. This can be worked around by writing the BPMN in the correct order

Comment: The problem is that there is no correct oder. You can have cycles, parallel gateways, exclusive gateways etc

Comment: Makes sense.. so if can add one more question. If I have to display the complete workflow as a visualization for the user upfront, what do you  suggest?

Comment: If you want to see the workflow I would suggest that you look at https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/blob/master/modules/flowable-ui-admin/flowable-ui-admin-app/src/main/resources/static/display/bpmn-draw.js. That is used in the Flowable UI Applications

Answer (score -1):

You can create a [TaskQuery](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/task/get-query/)

```java
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngine;
...

@Autowired
private ProcessEngine processEngine;

private List<Task> getAllTaskByProcessId(string processInstanceId){
  return processEngine.getTaskService()
    .createTaskQuery()
    .processInstanceId(processInstanceId)
    .list();
}
```

Comment: The question is on flowable. And your code will just list all User task not the Service tasks.